# Run a script after location is changed

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve something like this:

```
location.replace("some url");
alert("hello");
```

I know this won't work but it runs before the next page is loaded and `onload` doesn't seem to work either is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So on which page do you want the script to execute? On the old page that’s being navigated away from, or on the new page that’s being navigated to? It’s not clear in your question what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Terry On the new page

Comment: If the new page is on the same domain, you can set a flag in local storage or session storage before navigating away: then the new page reads this flag and runs whatever logic you want it to at runtime, and you unset the flag. You can also use query string but that means the user can replay it by reloading the same URL.

Comment: It will not be in same domain, in know a way , which is to put some function with parameter in the new page. While it is practical , it is not impressive as what I am trying to do for my project .

Comment: If it’s a CORS thing, you can’t. Otherwise this would be a major security issue. Imagine a rogue site redirecting user to a banking site and then being able to trigger code execution remotely.

Comment: What is a CORS ?

Comment: @Terry If you are wondering what am I actually trying to do becuase it's obvious no one want to alert hello in a website. I am trying to insert a malware to a government website and conquer the whole country ( just kidding ).I am trying to change inner html of some elements via this method. I know it is simple the normal way, but it is a class project and people will be around , so....,it is a good time to show wisdom with these crazy things ( and maybe , just maybe impress someone )

Comment: As I said, it’s a security issue and would never have been possible. No browser is going to care if it’s for a class project or a genuine hacker attempting to remotely manipulate DOM.

Comment: So what is CORS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: CORS is not really even relevant here; it's always been impossible for one website to run arbitrary scripts on another website, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -1):

So, I finally came to the conclusion that, it is not possible and thanks to @Terry for helping me understand why ( it is a security issue ).

But I got an alternative method for what I want to do. I will copy the website I wanted to run script on and I will host it in another site and I will change the address bar url to what I want by including a script to the site I cloned, hopefully no one notice.

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible idea. Your plan is straight up theft.  Please reconsider.

Comment: Uhm, I don't think so the page is created by some former nerd in my school and it is about the school like a wiki. Our teacher gave permission to screw around the page.